# Swift- How do I make it so that if the user clicks the button it takes them to a new view?

Tags: swift

I'm currently trying to create a small notepad app, and i'm in need of help. I am using a Tabbed View Application. Say we had a view that has two text fields for Name and short description, and then a button beneath saying "Create Note".

How can I make this button change the view to my editor/notepad view that does not have the tabs at the bottom? 
Thanks

Comment: This is is a very broad question and you provide no indication of having tried anything. Please consider rewriting the question to be much more specific.

Comment: I have tried a lot.. i'm asking a question because I have no idea..

Answer (score 0):

*If you are using storyboards*, which I assume that you are, what you will want to use are triggered movements called **segues**.

To create one, **right-click on the button** and **drag the line** that appears to the second view, and **then release**.

It should look like this:

[image: drag]

Then, *when you release*, a **gray box will appear**, with a **list of segues**. You can find out what each one does online, and as you get more advanced you can develop custom ones.

However, use *Modal as a basic one* to begin with.

Hope this helps,

**Will.**

*PS. In the future, try and make your questions more specific, and do some research before you ask a question. It's important that you gain a good reputation on Stack Overflow if you want your questions answered properly.*